# Tool to monitor the health / performance and statistics of our Elasticsearch, logstash, spark and kafka a installed on the Server

Tags: performance-analysis, statistics, health, centos-7

Server Information:

Server OS : **CentOS 7.8**

Installed Applications:

**A)    SPARK (v2.4.3_2.11)**

**B)    KAFKA (v2.3.0_2.11)**

**C)    ELASTICEARCH (6.x)**

**D)    LOGSTASH (6.x)**

Problem Statement:

What are the **free** tools **to monitor the health / performance and statistics** of our applications installed on the Server.

We want to monitor those applications **remotely** using **Window 8 OS**.

With my research I found metricbeat for monitoring Elasticsearch. For rest of the applications I am still searching.

What are the best options we have to do this?

Comment: Sounds like 4 different questions to me...

Comment: Actually, yes , 4 applications, each require a tool to monitor. For 1 i found, for remaining I am still searching

Comment: That was a hint to split up your 'question'. If a question remains for ElasticSearch make sure to follow [this](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/48/how-to-ask-for-an-alternative-to-some-software). While you're editing remove the unneccesary bold emphasis and add a [gratis] tag. You could also describe *monitor the health / performance and statistics* a little more specifically - what data and in what format/what output?